# PDOException : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '308' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node}

Tags: drupal

I have a big issue today on my website using Drupal 7.22.

This issue appear on new node creation from an admin.

PDOException : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '308' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, sticky, tnid, translate) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 308 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 308 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => evenements [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => fr [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => TEST [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1381931095 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 1381931095 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => 0 ) dans drupal_write_record() (ligne 7136 dans /var/www/carioca/includes/common.inc).

I have checked the database and the last node id is 294.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PhpMyAdmin for your Database, have a look at the tables: node & node_revision. Could be that you have different indexes in there and causes that the id cannot be inserted.

Your issue is not that there is already an entry in the DB but that node & node_revision (or other table) has different state as the other tables does. The data within your DB seems to not be consistent.

Are you having custom table handles within your modules? Fix the Id issues and use the node_load or user_load Drupal API functions instead of custom DB calls.

If you are on Drupal 6 have a look into the node_counter table where there could be a older value.

Comment: You are so so great Francis :-) You are my turning point of my project (y).

Answer (score -1):

When executing the following mysql query, do you have a result?

```
SELECT * FROM node WHERE nid = 308;
```

Comment: Nothing, as explained, the last nid id in the table is 294.

Comment: oops !!! In fact, it was a rule that cause the problem.
This rule was used to remove node from the sitemap if they are not published.
When this rule is used, some values are changed in the node then the node is saved.
I have desactivated the rule and everything is working fine now.
Sorry for this, I just have to find an other way to have the nodes correctly removed from then sitemap.

Comment: Ok :), strange that the nid changes for nodes that you don't want to be included in the sitemap. Which module are you using the generate a sitemap?

Comment: I use XML sitemap 7.x-2.0-rc2, but there is a problem with it : Unpublished nodes are published in the site map, causing exploration error with Google Bot.
That why I have create a rule to remove the unpublished nodes from the sitemap.

Comment: I've just tested with same module version / release (7.x-2.0-rc2). Unpublished nodes are not included in the sitemap xml but it is not directly updated. Imagine you have node published, xml sitemap is generated (referencing your node), node is unpublished ... you need to wait for next cron in order the sitemap xml is regenerated (which will will remove the unpublished node). Maybe hook on the node_update, and regenerated it yourself in a custom module?